# Rancid keeps sending to the wrong addresses after changing aliases

Tags: centos, postfix

I have been troubleshooting a rancid install for some time now.
I cannot get rancid to send to the correct email address after making changes to the aliases
The `LIST_OF_GROUPS="mygroup"` variable is set in `/etc/rancid/rancid.config` and the corresponding alias record in the `/etc/aliases` file is set: `rancid-mygroup: user@contoso.com`. I've ran the newaliases command several times.
below are the mail logs.

Just to be clear it pulls configs and sends email but since the email/group stuff is not correct they get dropped.

```
Jun 13 12:15:42 rancid postfix/pickup[27906]: 3B69A214FC: uid=498 from=<rancid>
Jun 13 12:15:42 rancid postfix/cleanup[28607]: 3B69A214FC: message-id=<20170613191542.3B69A214FC@RANCID.contoso.com>
Jun 13 12:15:42 rancid postfix/qmgr[22342]: 3B69A214FC: from=<rancid@contoso.com>, size=4194, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 13 12:15:42 rancid postfix/smtp[28615]: 3B69A214FC: to=<rancid-mygroup@contoso.com>, orig_to=<rancid-mygroup>, relay=192.168.40.74[192.168.40.74]:25, delay=0.13, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.1, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0  <20170613191542.3B69A214FC@RANCID.contoso.com> Queued mail for delivery)
Jun 13 12:15:42 rancid postfix/qmgr[22342]: 3B69A214FC: removed
```

**Version:
rancid version 3.1-3.el6 --
postfix version-2.6.6-6.el6_5 --
cetnos 6.6 --**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/etc/aliases is used for local delivery. Note the comments at the top of /etc/postfix/virtual:

```
#    The  optional  virtual(5)  alias  table rewrites recipient
#        addresses for all local, all virtual, and all remote  mail
#        destinations.   This  is unlike the aliases(5) table which
#        is used only for local(8) delivery.  Virtual  aliasing  is
#        recursive,  and  is  implemented by the Postfix cleanup(8)
#        daemon before mail is queued.
```

You want to add to /etc/postfix/virtual the line (notice, no colon):

```
rancid-mygroup user@contoso.com
# You may also need
rancid-mygroup@contoso.com  user@contoso.com
```

Then create the hash:

```
postmap hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Then add line to /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Restart Postfix and test. Emails sent to rancip-mygroup should get sent to user@contoso.com.

Comment: let me give that a go and see if it sticks. Thanks

Comment: This worked my friend! Il have to see if it takes multiple emails for the same rancid-group alias so I can send this to multiple emails for one single group.

Comment: It should a comma separated list of destination addresses, see `man 5 virtual`.